# I am leaking memory in my JavaScript with my custom preload function, but I don't know where

Tags: javascript, performance, memory

I created a photo app. It runs in the browser, and what it does is this:

it runs every minute, goes to the server to get a random filename (from all the files on the server) with `randomfilename.php`, then load and places that in a hidden image named 'next' (`image.php?filename=`).
Then the next minute, it puts the image from the hidden 'next' image in the image called 'current', (the image called 'current' is what the user sees) and then it loads another image from the server in 'next'. And so on.

The reason I first preload the image in the 'next' image, is that it runs on a Raspberry Pi and it's not so quick in loading the image. When it takes 2 or 3 seconds, it doesn't look so smooth.

So now it has almost a minute to get the image and put it in 'next', and then instant it loads in 'current' (what the user sees) with this code: `document.getElementById('current').src = document.getElementById('next').src;`

This works....until the browser kept crashing, and when loading it from my pc and inspect memory, I saw the browser memory go up and up, and I understand why the limited memory Pi would crash.
So first I deleted all console.logs, didn't help.
Then I commented the code to load the image in next, and the code to copy the image from 'next' to 'current'. So the script was still getting the filename and the image from server, but didn't do anything with it. And at this time the memory didn't go up.

So I am wondering, what am I doing wrong with my setup? Does it hold all images in memory, doesn't it free memory from the previous image when I load a new one in 'next' and in 'current'?

Do I have to say (pseudocode) `document.getElementById('current').clear()` or remove it from DOM and then create a new one?

All help and tips on my code is welcome.

**EDIT 1: the memory usage:**
I've created 3 snapshots in FireFox, at t=0, t=.5 hours and t = 7 hours, it's 3.1 , 4.85 and 3.55 MB. So not a lot.

The same moments, the memory usage of FireFox in the task manager: 450 Mb, 943 MB and 4902 MB. So this is quite a lot.

Could it be that all images are stored/cached/remembered in the tabpage?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var currentFileName = '';
        var nextFileName = '';
        var latestRetrievedFile = 'pending...';
        setInterval( refreshAfbeelding , 60000 );
        
        function refreshAfbeelding(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('current').src = document.getElementById('next').src;               
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $( "#current" ).fadeTo( 1500 , 1, function() {
                        d = new Date().toISOString();
                        $.get( "randomfilename.php?id=" + d, function( data ) {
                            data = $.trim(data);
                            parts = data.split("|");
                            document.getElementById('next').src = "image.php?filename=" + parts[1];
                            latestRetrievedFile = parts[0];
                        }); 
                        
                    });
                }, 0);
            }, 1500);
            $( "#current" ).fadeTo( 1500 , 0, function() {
            });
        };
});
```

**Edit 2**
Even with the simplest code, without fade en nifty timeouts, it still creates the same amount of memory, in the Windows process

```
var currentFileName = '';
var nextFileName = '';
var latestRetrievedFile = 'pending...';
var currentFileName = '/twee.jpg';
var nextFileName = '/een.jpg';

function refreshAfbeelding() {
    document.getElementById('current').src = document.getElementById('next').src;
    document.getElementById("imagename").innerHTML = latestRetrievedFile;

    var d = new Date().toISOString();
    $.get( "randomfilename.php?id=" + d, function( data ) {
        var dataTrimmed = $.trim(data);
        var parts = dataTrimmed.split("|");
        document.getElementById('next').src = "image.php?filename=" + parts[1];
        latestRetrievedFile = parts[0];
        
    });     
}
setInterval( refreshAfbeelding , 60000 );
```

Comment: You need to clear your timeouts with clearTimeout method.

Comment: @lingthe _"The `clearTimeout()` method of the `WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope` mixin **cancels a timeout** previously established by calling `setTimeout()`"_ - How does cancelling a timeout do anything useful for OP?

Comment: _"...and inspect memory"_ - How did you do this? The developer tools in your browser will tell you loads of useful information about the memory used by the active tab. Take multiple snapshots and compare them. Step through the different options and visualizations, ...

Comment: And inspect memory... good question. I took memory snapshots in Firefox in the dev tools, and they stayed constant (will do that again to be sure) but I saw the memory of Firefox in the taskmanager going up. (when I added more 'next' images, just to see what it would do, the memory went up even quicker )

Comment: Can you do var d = new Date() instead of d = new Date() and see if it leaks anything.

Comment: @nicholasnet I will try that tomorrow

Comment: Cool same goes for parts too

Comment: Unfortunately the 'var's didn't make a difference.

Comment: I don't know that the memory performance characteristics of a browser running on a Windows desktop machine will transfer to a browser running on a (Linux?) Raspberry Pi. Then again, without knowing the actual images, HTML structure, etc., that are being used, I'm not sure we'd be able to help pin down a root cause for whatever problem you're seeing.

Comment: I also don't know if the memory charasteristics can be transferred to a Pi linux version. But I do know that both memory usages behave the same. Images are size 1 - 4 MB, and the html structure is very limited: it only contains the 2 mentioned divs named 'current' and 'next' and 1 div for the title of the image.